# Starting out with Visual Studio 2015 with C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

[image]

I am brand new to programming and I was told I should use visual studio for an IDE and compiler as it is one of the best. I read some tutorials on how to use it but I am running into trouble.

I am trying to start a new project so here is what I am doing:

> New Project > Win32 Console Application (Visual c++) > OK > Finish.

Whenever the new project loads, there is nothing there. I am told to go to source files and add a c++ file to begin coding. However, the only thing present in the solution explorer is "Solution 'ConsoleApplication1' (0 projects). There is nothing under it.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

^Did I do that right?

I tried running devenv /installvstemplates and got :

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10586] (c) 2015 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. 
C:\Users\tanner>devenv /installvstemplates 
'devenv' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: There should be a project. Can you post [a screenshot](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/take-screen-capture-print-screen#take-screen-capture-print-screen=windows-7)? (Note: when you edit your question there is a button for adding an image)

Comment: There should be a project under the solution. I tried it here and it worked. Are there any error messages?

Comment: Try resetting the project template cache by running `devenv /installvstemplates` from the command line (while VS is closed). If that doesn't help, try repairing your Visual Studio installation (in Windows's Programs and Features, right-click on it and choose 'Repair').

Comment: Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10586]
(c) 2015 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\tanner>devenv /installvstemplates
'devenv' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\tanner>

Comment: @TannerTemoshenko: One way to do this is to first `cd /d somewhere` where `somewhere` is the path to the directory where `devenv` resides. One way to find that directory is to look in the text produced by `set vs`. I posted an [example at pastie.org](http://pastie.org/10791631).

Comment: It can be easier – but *much* more time consuming (maybe hours) – to just reinstall.

Comment: I'm repairing it now... see what happens. I'm running my laptop off of my phone at work and don't really have the data to be reinstalling.